# How to end a While-Loop when value is met inside a Nested List in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, while-loop, nested-loops

I have a nested List and I am trying to end a while-loop when a value inside the nested loop is searched through For-Loop. My problem is it is looping forever.

```
listA = [
['a','b'], # 0, -5
['b','c'], # 1, -4
['c','d'], # 2, -3
['a','d'], # 3, -2
['b','e'], # 4, -1
]

endpoint = 'c'
point = ''
while point is not endpoint:
    for sets in listA:
        for point in sets:
            print(point)
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
a
b
b
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yash's answer does the job.

Another way you can do it is by defining a function and returning when point is equal to endpoint.

```py
listA = [
['a','b'], # 0, -5
['b','c'], # 1, -4
['c','d'], # 2, -3
['a','d'], # 3, -2
['b','e'], # 4, -1
]

endpoint = 'c'

def foo(items, endpoint):
    for sets in items:
        for point in sets:
            print(point)
            if point == endpoint:
                return

foo(listA, endpoint)
```

But to answer your question why it doesn't work, it is because the second `for` loop will always execute completely and the value of point will **always** be the last value of the last set in the list (in this case `'e'`). So that is why the while loop will run forever as it will always check if 'e' is not 'c' evaluating to true.

If you want to keep your old solution you can do this:

```py
listA = [
['a','b'], # 0, -5
['b','c'], # 1, -4
['c','d'], # 2, -3
['a','d'], # 3, -2
['b','e'], # 4, -1
]

endpoint = 'c'
point = ''
while point != endpoint:
    for sets in listA:
        for point in sets:
            print(point)
            if endpoint == point:
                break
        else: 
            continue
        break
```

It is basically braking from the nested `for` loops when `point` is equal to `endpoint`.

As you can see you check if point and endpoint are the same twice (in the `if endpoint == point` and in the while loop), so the while loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is more clearer and your explanation was truly amazing. I didn't know I can use Else condition within For-Loop.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. In Python you can :) you can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html, section 4.4.

Answer (score 4):

you can do:-

```py
listA = [
['a','b'], # 0, -5
['b','c'], # 1, -4
['c','d'], # 2, -3
['a','d'], # 3, -2
['b','e'], # 4, -1
]

endpoint = 'c'
done = False
for sets in listA:
    if done:
        break
    for point in sets:
        print(point)
        if point == endpoint:
            done=True
            break
```

Comment: This works great! However, I want to understand further, I can see that the variable 'done' is a boolean and I want to know how is it effective and mine wasn't when it seemed really simple?

Comment: because in your code the program was inside the "for loop" and your "while condition" was outside of that "for loop". But in mine code, I have set the break statement inside of the "for loops"

Comment: I see. I kind of understood it. Thanks for clearing that out!